# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.util.ArrayList

Tags: hibernate, restrictions

I tried to map the groupIds list into the sqlrestriction below but got the error.  How should I map it?

```
 List<String> groupIds = new ArrayList<String>();
  ...
  ...

    Restrictions.sqlRestriction(
       "{alias}.id in (select id from table where group_id in ?)",
       groupIds, Hibernate.OBJECT
    )
```

Comment: Please post the complete entity, also let us know is it a joined table or what

Comment: One way is to set comma separated group id manually in one string variable and use this string variable in IN CLAUSE

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Hibernate does not automatically expand non-persistent collections in query conditions. You have to enlist the single groupId's manually.